# How to tell if OpenMP is working?

Tags: c++, openmp, libsvm

I am trying to run LIBSVM in parallel mode, however my question is in OpenMP in general. According to [LIBSVM FAQ](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f432), I have modified the code with #pragma calls to use OpenMP. I also modified the Makefile (for un*x) by adding a -fopenmp argument so it becomes:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wconversion -O3 -fPIC -fopenmp
```

The code compiles well. I check (since it's not my PC) whether OpenMP is installed by :

```
/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep gomp
```

and see that it is -probably- installed:

```
 libgomp.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1
 libgomp.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libgomp.so.1
```

Now; when I run the program, I don't see any speed improvements. Also when I check with "top" the process is using at most %100 CPU (there are 8 cores), also there is not a CPU bottleneck (only one more user with %100 CPU usage), I was expecting to see more than %100 (or a different indicator) that process is using multiple cores.

Is there a way to check that it is working multiple core?

Comment: Just a thought, but shouldn't it be max. 100%/number of cores when only one thread is running?

Comment: no, when multicores are employed (at least in my server's installation) we see values much larger than 100%

Comment: @Tibor, top defaults to Irix mode that shows 100% for the full load of a single CPU and n*100% for the full load of n CPUs. If you toggle Irix mode off (press 'I') it shows 100% when all CPUs are used.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the function `omp_get_num_threads()`. It will return you the number of threads that are used by your program.

Comment: One must call `omp_get_num_threads()` inside a parallel region. Otherwise it always returns 1!

Answer (score 2):

With `omp_get_max_threads()` you get the maximum number of threads available to your program. It is also the maximum of all possible return values of `omp_get_num_threads()`. You can explicitly set the number of threads to be used by your program with the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS`, e.g. in bash via

```
$export OMP_NUM_THREADS=8; your_program
```